# VisualForce Email Template - Error: Syntax error If Condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx, email-template, singleemailmessage

Getting `Error: Syntax error` when i tried to add the below condition in Visual-force Email Template
with dynamic variable

`{!IF(recipient.RecordType.Name  != 'Guardian',{!relatedTo.Name__c}, {!relatedTo.Name__c} )}`

[image]

Can anyone help me what i am missing here

Answer (score 1):

This statement alone will not work when visualforce is compiled but I am pretty sure you are simply trying to output a custom field on the `relatedTo` when the `recipient` does not match a certain Record Type. Quick tip, if your condition is producing the same output for both boolean expressions, a refactor is needed.

We can start first by making use of the `apex:outputText` attribute which gives us the ability to "render" a message/value based on a condition such as `recipient.RecordType.Name != "Guardian"`.

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(recipient.RecordType.Name != "Guardian", true, false)}" value="{!relatedTo.Name}"/>
```

Note, when using `relatedTo` you will be asked to also define a `relatedToType` in your `messaging:emailTemplate` attribute of the visualforce email template. This is the SObject from which the template retrieves merge field data.

You may also place such render in an outer block such as a panel if you have an if-else flow.